# How to switch on an LED when I press mouse button using a transistor instead of a coin cell

Tags: transistors, led

I have been asked to modify an optical mouse so that an LED switches on when one of the mouse buttons is pressed. I've found some information online where a coin cell is used, this appears to be because the logic in the mouse can't provide enough current to drive the LED and when the mouse button is pressed it pulls the input to the ic low (?).

While I don't really understand electronics enough to design a circuit and select the correct component values, I'm sure this can be done with a simple transistor circuit instead of using a battery.[image: mouse pcb]

The optical sensor is a [PixArt PAW3552DB](https://www.pixart.com/products-detail/23/PAW3552DB-VJXT) which I have been able to find a basic datasheet on but it didn't seem to have any useful information.

**It's a USB mouse and I only need to switch on the LED when the left button is pressed.**

Please can someone help?

Comment: `While I don't really understand electronics enough to design a circuit and select the correct component values, I'm sure this can be done with a simple transistor circuit instead of using a battery` - how can you be so sure?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, well I can't be sure, this is why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on this project? pictures would be a start.
So if I get this correctly, you have any number of buttons that are used to switch signals towards some kind of IC, and you want to illuminate some kind of LED using the power of the internal battery, without affecting the original switching signal that is going to the internal IC of the mouse?
An transistor might help you, or not. Really need some more details.
Also the mouse is quite cramped. Do you have the soldering skill to work with small components?

Comment: @Darryl you did say `I'm sure` so, if you are not so sure, you should amend your question.

Comment: Is it a USB mouse? Or a battery powered device?

Comment: It's a USB mouse and I only need to switch on the LED when the left button is pressed. I'm struggling to add my picture to this comment but working on it now. In the meantime, I can say that there's plenty of room inside for small modifications, and while I might not be good at circuit design (completely hopeless to be frank) I'm good at following instructions and very handy with a soldering iron! I can identify the +5v input and the microswitch connections, I hope that would be enough to get going?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please draw a schematic of what you have and what you are proposing. Click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: If it's a USB mouse you have 5V to power the LED. You need to suss out whether the switch is normally grounded and pulls up to 5V when depressed or whether it's normally pulled up to 5V and grounded when depressed. Depending on that would dictate what type of FET to use for the switching. (I think a FET would likely be preferable to a BJT.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you need an LED when the switch is tactile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that J1 connector a USB from your computer? Just use an output of your IC to drive a transistor from USB 5V power. In the below circuit you need to calculate the values of the resistor accordingly to the currents you expect to go through your LED (usually 330 ohm) and IC. Use their respective datasheets to do so.

Edit: In case that you want to wire the LED directly to the button, just connect in series the button, 330 ohm resistor, LED and 5V power.

[image: LED driving circuit]

<sub>Image source: [Figure 9: Driving an LED via a transistor (NPN) driver.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Driving-an-LED-via-a-transistor-NPN-driver-A-logic-1-output-is-required-to-light-the_fig2_255636371) from - Pont, Michael & Ong, Royan & Parikh, Chinmay & Kureemun, Ridwan & Wong, Chen & Peasgood, William & Li, Yuhua. (1999). A SELECTION OF PATTERNS FOR RELIABLE EMBEDDED SYSTEMS.</sub>

Comment: Alex Ghilas - Hi, As required by [this site rule](/help/referencing), when you include something in an answer (e.g. photo, image or text) which isn't your own original work, you need to properly reference (cite) it. That image has come from somewhere else, so in order to comply with that rule, it must be referenced. I found what I believe to be the original source and added that reference for you this time. Please can you do that in future? Thanks. (Also, if you copied the image from a different website, please update the citation which I added.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I managed to get this working by adding the led with a current limiting resistor in series with the microswitch.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIiIPJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looking at the photos, I believe your switch can handle 10mA  to ground and the supply side might be on the other side of the R10 resistor.  (Verify)

Comment: Good for SW2, but I don't see a path from any of the SW1 pins to GND.

Comment: SW1 is switching from the supply I think (instead of ground). That thick trace from the middle of SW1 is also going to the infrared led pin labeled with V+ on the top side. So you might use the same led wiring construction but then inverted?
The OP can just measure across the uninstalled C16 to measure for supply.

Comment: The OP only needs SW2 @Thijs

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the addition the op made to the post. +1 for the simplicity of this solution

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sure this can be done with a simple transistor circuit instead of using a battery.

Based on the second photo - maybe.

It takes both.  You need a 1-transistor amplifier (in this case, operating as a saturated switch) to amplify the very low signal currents in a mouse circuit up to a current value that is high enough to power an LED.  You also need a power source for the added LED.

From the photos, it looks like you are working with a wired USB mouse.  If so, then 5 V available in there with more than enough extra current capacity to power the added LED.